# Communicate React<->Angular Iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I know people will say don't do this or why use both.. but I have to.

I need to pass data from React(child) to Angular (parent) to React(child) in an iframe.

So far I can use `window.postMessage` from React to angular with `@HostListener`, the issue is that (and I think) is that the window attribute is getting refreshed every time I use `postMessage`. Within React, there are components that use `componentDidUpdate` and this causes an entire refresh within react component once I click/select within react.

I can't do react to react because there are things that needs to be passed up to angular parent.

[image]

React side:

```
//some item is selected in react
onSelect = selected => {
    window.parent.postMessage(
      {
        activeData:tselected
      },
      '*'
    )
  }
```

sends to angular in iframe

```
@HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
    onMessage(e) {
      this.selection = e['data'];
  }
```

output looks great but then the entire window gets refreshed to original blank state once it is selected.

Comment: Where do you have this HostListener? There is definitely not enough info in your question

Comment: @smnbbrv how is this not enough info? but anyways, hostlistener is in angular component.

Comment: Long version: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Short version: post the stackblitz example. Nobody wants to answer questions where one needs to spend 1 hour to reproduce the issue (and there is still a chance that issue is not going to be reproduced).

Comment: @smnbbrv thank you for the gentle comment

Answer (score 1):

I can see a lot of advantages of using Angular & ReactJS in one project. You can simple divide code, use Angular as a router & parent container, and implement React components on demand. It's very good idea. In old project you can in this way have a little innovation and use different technologies so you can develop new sills.

The easiest answer on your question how to pass data between angular & react is to use RxJS and subscription or Redux. In this way you can use one Redux store in few application, or pass one BehaviorSubject.

I'm not recommend you using `events` and `post.messages` for communication. It's unnecessary and you should support all kind of problems. Why if you have a ready solutions like RxJS or Redux?

If you use RxJS in ReactJS you can simply use `comopnentDidMount()` with subscription, like this:

```
  componentDidMount(): void {
    // In componentDidMount we subscribe heroes$ object
    this.props.heroes$.subscribe((res: IHero[]) => {
      // and we pass this data into React State object
      this.setState({heroes: res});
    });
  }
```

If you look for demo, you can get it from [github](https://github.com/qubiack/angular-reactjs) where I create repo with minimal version of communication between Angular 7 app and React 16

If you need 2 separate React implementation it's not a problem to extend presented solutions. Look also hire: [Connect Angular application with ReactJS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app)